# How to run multiple jmeter scripts from command

Tags: jmeter

How can we run multiple jmeter scripts from command line.I have following scripts
test1.jmx
test2.jmx
test3.jmx

Now if i want to pass threads and loop from command line,How can i do that?I know for one script, we can use syntax as follows
THREADS    ${__P("threads", 25)}
but how can we do that for multiple scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JMeter integrated with Apache Ant through the [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)

For instance, you can configure your execution like this

[image]

The key is the line where you specify multiple test plans:

testplans dir="/path/to/your/test" includes="*.jmx"

Look the way to pass properties:

```
property name="loop" value="10"
property name="threads" value="50"
property name="ramp" value="100"
```

you read properties from your testplan using the sintax:

${__P([property],[defaultvalue])}.

In this case you will have:

[image]

Comment: This is for one script but i have multiple flow scripts in my script.How can i handle multiple scripts

Comment: what do you mean? I understood, two questions 1)you had three files (test1.jmx test2.jmx test3.jmx) and you wanted to run them. So with Ant Task you can fire them all in sequence and collect the result in a file. 2)You needed to configure options like threads and loop, so you can use properties.If you have several Thread Group
in the same file, You will use differents properties, for instance:test1.jmx has two thread group, use two properties ${__P(threads-1)} and ${__P(threads-2)}(this way you can manage every flow independently)

Comment: Thanks Fernando.If i want to read thread and loop values from csv/excel file and pass it to shell script by using above scenario.How can i do that.

Comment: My example has three properties loops,threads and ramp. You can give them values that you read before from a csv, by 
embedding a scripting language like groovy in your build.xml. This script will read the file(csv) and
set the properties before you uses them in the tag jmeter.

Comment: Like if we have 3 scripts as i mentioned above in my test plan.So if i pass following values